# Is there a jig for standard door handles?

Tags: doors

I can't seem to find a jig for standard lever handles. There only seems to be jigtech available. The hole for my spindle is too big for the handles and would be seen. Is there a jig for these types of handles? I have a lot of doors to fit and a jig would save me a bit of time.

Comment: Make one, to match what you need - perhaps fill that hole and re-drill to the correct size...

Comment: Typically a jig is something a carpenter would make to suit their needs or the requirements of a certain job.  Pre-made jigs for the most common tasks are a modern convenience, but making your own is still an important skill.

Comment: **There is no jig to make a hole smaller**.  As mike said you need to fill the hole and re-drill, there are door knob hole jigs on the market or you could make your own.